# How to handle log analysis from several servers?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, logging

I’m stuck which way to go with log analysis. I have a bunch of small VM’s (web + database server) running with Ubuntu 12.04. Right now I log weekly into each machine and grep system logs and Apache error/access logs for events. This starts to get really complicated and labor intensive.

I’m looking for a way to automatically collect automatically all logs of my interest, and analyze them to find system bottlenecks and things like DDoS attacks. To be more precise, I found [logsurfer](http://www.crypt.gen.nz/logsurfer/) and [logwatch](http://sourceforge.net/projects/logwatch/) which could do the job but both have there last updates over a year ago. does one can suggest a fitting solution?

thanks,
anatol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can look into http://www.splunk.com/ or something like http://www.fluentd.org/architecture ?

Comment: Could you give some information about why those links are useful? For example, a brief summary of the main features of the software you're linking to.

Comment: Hi Peter thanks for your tip, I tried splunk light which fits quite good. The documentation is exemplary. As I have ansible in use its quite easy to fetch logs from different servers and feed splunk. thanks t book